# How to import cache setup into views.py

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, django-views

I have a seperate code for cache creation in another file in my project directory...

`authentication.py`

```
caches_folder = "./.spotify_caches/"
if not os.path.exists(caches_folder):
    os.makedirs(caches_folder)

def session_cache_path():
    return caches_folder + request.session.get("uuid")


oauth = SpotifyOAuth(
redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:8000/spotify/authorize",
scope='user-library-read',
show_dialog=True,
cache_path=session_cache_path()
)
```

So I am trying to use the oauth in `views.py` by importing `from .authentication import oauth`

`views.py`

```
def login(request):
if not request.session.get("uuid"):
   request.session["uuid"] = str(uuid.uuid4())
authorize_url = oauth.get_authorize_url()
return redirect(authorize_url)
```

ERROR : `return caches_folder + request.session.get("uuid") NameError: name 'request' is not defined`

I reckon it is because `request.session.get("uuid")` is defined outside a view but I do not want to be creating `oauth` in separate views all the time. How do I manage this best?

edit:

```
def session_cache_path(uu_id):
return caches_folder + uu_id


oauth = SpotifyOAuth(
redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:8000/spotify/authorize",
scope='user-library-read',
show_dialog=True,
cache_path=session_cache_path(uu_id)
)
```

Comment: Update the function to accept the uuid as a parameter, and pass it in to the function when you call it.  The caller should have access to the session, right?

Comment: @JohnGordon If I do that, in the `authentication.py` file, there'll be an error in `oauth` because `uu_id` will still be undefined because I haven't called it in a session yet. Check edit for new code

Comment: If you call it outside of a session, then what do you expect uuid to be?

Comment: @JohnGordon okay what if I do a `str(uuid.uuid4())` in `authentication.py` and assign the value to the function call in auth and import it to my views?

Comment: It would help if you edited your post to use proper indentation.  As it is, we can't tell what code is supposed to be in a function, and what code is at the main level.

Answer (score 0):

I did  a `str(uuid.uuid4())` in `authentication.py` and assigned the value to the function call in `oauth` and import it to my views